# Print Celero output CSV file in LaTEX

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, csv

Is there an appropriate, fast way to print the [Celero](https://github.com/DigitalInBlue/Celero) output (CSV) as a table?

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice way to print it in landscape, multi-page way:
You need the following packages: `ltablex`,`multirow` and `pgfplotstable`.

```
\begin{landscape}
\newcommand{\headerCSV}{Group & Experiment & Problem Space & Samples & Iterations & Baseline & us/Iteration & Iterations/sec & Min (us) & Mean (us) & Max (us) & Variance & Standard Deviation & Skewness & Kurtosis & Z Score} % own Header
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt} % save inner margin space
{\tiny
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{diagrams/results.csv}\data % Your CSV file
 \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    begin table=\begin{tabularx}{\hsize},
    % Multi Page setup:
    every first row/.append style={before row={%
        \headerCSV \\ \hline
     \endfirsthead
         \multicolumn{16}{c}%
         {\textbf{Continued from previous page}} \\
         \hline
         \headerCSV \\ \hline
     \endhead
         \hline 
         \multicolumn{16}{c}%
         {\textbf{Continued on next page}} \\
     \endfoot
         \hline
         \multicolumn{16}{|r|}{{Concluded}} \\ 
         \hline
     \endlastfoot
     }
 },%
    end table=\end{tabularx},
    %
    column type/.add={|}{},
    empty cells with={---}, %replace empty cells with ’--’
    % Custom columns settings for every Celero output row
    columns/Group/.style={string type, column type=|l},
    columns/Experiment/.style={string type, column type=|l},
    columns/Problem Space/.style={string replace={-9223372036854775808}{}, column type=|X}, % no Problem Space --> empty
    columns/Samples/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Iterations/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Baseline/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/us/Iteration/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Iterations/sec/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Min (us)/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Mean (us)/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Max (us)/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Variance/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Standard Deviation/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Skewness/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Kurtosis/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Z Score/.style={column type=|X|},
    every head row/.style={%
        after row=\hline,output empty row
    },
    columns={Group,Experiment,Problem Space,Samples,Iterations,Baseline,us/Iteration,Iterations/sec,Min (us),Mean (us),Max (us),Variance,Standard Deviation,Skewness,Kurtosis,Z Score},%
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
   /pgf/number format/precision=5,
]{\data}
} % end tiny
\end{landscape}
```

Example PDF:
[image: First page]
[image: Second page]

EDIT: 
Credits to [@harish-kumar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195691/csv-table-overflow-with-csv-simple) for the basic concept.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
    pdftex,
    a4paper, 
    %letterpaper,
    oneside,        % Einseitiger Druck.
    12pt,           % Schriftgroesse
    parskip=half,   % Halbe Zeile Abstand zwischen Absätzen.
%   headsepline,    % Linie nach Kopfzeile.
    footsepline,    % Linie vor Fusszeile.
    plainfootsepline,
    abstracton,     % Abstract Überschriften
    english,        % Translator
    %enabledeprecatedfontcommands, %enable old commands ot use fancyhdr NOT RECOMMENDED
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{ltablex} % mix out of tabularx and longtable
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\newcommand{\headerCSV}{Group & Experiment & Problem Space & Samples & Iterations & Baseline & us/Iteration & Iterations/sec & Min (us) & Mean (us) & Max (us) & Variance & Standard Deviation & Skewness & Kurtosis & Z Score} % own Header
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt} % save inner margin space
{\tiny
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{results.csv}\data % Your CSV file
 \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    begin table=\begin{tabularx}{\hsize},
    % Multi Page setup:
    every first row/.append style={before row={%
        \headerCSV \\ \hline
     \endfirsthead
         \multicolumn{16}{c}%
         {\textbf{Continued from previous page}} \\
         \hline
         \headerCSV \\ \hline
     \endhead
         \hline 
         \multicolumn{16}{c}%
         {\textbf{Continued on next page}} \\
     \endfoot
         \hline
         \multicolumn{16}{|r|}{{Concluded}} \\ 
         \hline
     \endlastfoot
     }
 },%
    end table=\end{tabularx},
    %
    column type/.add={|}{},
    empty cells with={---}, %replace empty cells with ’--’
    % Custom columns settings for every Celero output row
    columns/Group/.style={string type, column type=|l},
    columns/Experiment/.style={string type, column type=|l},
    columns/Problem Space/.style={string replace={-9223372036854775808}{}, column type=|X}, % no Problem Space --> empty
    columns/Samples/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Iterations/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Baseline/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/us/Iteration/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Iterations/sec/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Min (us)/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Mean (us)/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Max (us)/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Variance/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Standard Deviation/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Skewness/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Kurtosis/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Z Score/.style={column type=|X|},
    every head row/.style={%
        after row=\hline,output empty row
    },
    columns={Group,Experiment,Problem Space,Samples,Iterations,Baseline,us/Iteration,Iterations/sec,Min (us),Mean (us),Max (us),Variance,Standard Deviation,Skewness,Kurtosis,Z Score},%
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
   /pgf/number format/precision=5,
]{\data}
} % end tiny
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Really Long name ...`: The `...` is within the name. The whole structure does not shorten any things!