# Automatically choose font size within Table

Tags: fonts, longtable, tabularx, ltablex

Is there any package/trick, that a `ltablex` `tabularx` table dynamically adapts its font size, so that the table takes up the whole page (in our case page height in landscape mode)?

Example/Use case:  [print Celero CSV file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326831/print-celero-output-csv-file-in-latex)

This example currently uses the font size `tiny` but this leads to some unused space. `small` leads to an overflow within the table.

EDIT: Tried out `adjustbox` and `resizebox`. I have some errors: 
I implemented it in the following way:

```
\documentclass[%
    pdftex,
    a4paper, 
    %letterpaper,
    oneside,        % Einseitiger Druck.
    12pt,           % Schriftgroesse
    parskip=half,   % Halbe Zeile Abstand zwischen Absätzen.
%   headsepline,    % Linie nach Kopfzeile.
    footsepline,    % Linie vor Fusszeile.
    plainfootsepline,
    abstracton,     % Abstract Überschriften
    english,        % Translator
    %enabledeprecatedfontcommands, %enable old commands ot use fancyhdr NOT RECOMMENDED
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{ltablex} % mix out of tabularx and longtable
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\newcommand{\headerCSV}{Group & Experiment & Problem Space & Samples & Iterations & Baseline & us/Iteration & Iterations/sec & Min (us) & Mean (us) & Max (us) & Variance & Standard Deviation & Skewness & Kurtosis & Z Score} % own Header
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt} % save inner margin space
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{results.csv}\data % Your CSV file
 \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    begin table=\begin{tabularx}{\hsize},
    % Multi Page setup:
    every first row/.append style={before row={%
        \headerCSV \\ \hline
     \endfirsthead
         \multicolumn{16}{c}%
         {\textbf{Continued from previous page}} \\
         \hline
         \headerCSV \\ \hline
     \endhead
         \hline 
         \multicolumn{16}{c}%
         {\textbf{Continued on next page}} \\
     \endfoot
         \hline
         \multicolumn{16}{|r|}{{Concluded}} \\ 
         \hline
     \endlastfoot
     }
 },%
    end table=\end{tabularx},
    %
    column type/.add={|}{},
    empty cells with={---}, %replace empty cells with ’--’
    % Custom columns settings for every Celero output row
    columns/Group/.style={string type, column type=|l},
    columns/Experiment/.style={string type, column type=|l},
    columns/Problem Space/.style={string replace={-9223372036854775808}{}, column type=|X}, % no Problem Space --> empty
    columns/Samples/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Iterations/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Baseline/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/us/Iteration/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Iterations/sec/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Min (us)/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Mean (us)/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Max (us)/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Variance/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Standard Deviation/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Skewness/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Kurtosis/.style={column type=|X},
    columns/Z Score/.style={column type=|X|},
    every head row/.style={%
        after row=\hline,output empty row
    },
    columns={Group,Experiment,Problem Space,Samples,Iterations,Baseline,us/Iteration,Iterations/sec,Min (us),Mean (us),Max (us),Variance,Standard Deviation,Skewness,Kurtosis,Z Score},%
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
   /pgf/number format/precision=5,
]{\data}
} % end tiny
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Receive the following errors:
[image: Error log from Texmaker]

It seems like there is a not closed object. Without the `resizebox` argument, it works fine.

Comment: Between `tiny` and `small` you have two font sizes… You also can play with `\tabcolsep`.

Comment: @Bernard this is a good idea but I want generally go away from a fixed defined font size and `tabcolsep` and dynamically adapt the size since every printed table has different names and numbers and this should be a template for all of them.

Comment: An option is use `\resizebox` from `graphicx` package. But its use for resize tables (together with font) is not recommended. In the most cases result is ugly and not what user expect ...

Comment: @Zarko OK. I will evaluate and try this :)

Comment: use an arbitrary font soze then use `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabula....}` to scale to the text width every other day people post here  with questions containg that construction, to be advised not to do that and use a fixed size such as `\small` instead to obtain some consistent document formatting. but if that's what you need, that's what you need...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle added informations about your suggested solution. :)

Comment: why are you using longtable????? You said it had to fit on a page, `\resizebox` only makes sense with `tabular`, you can't put a multi-page construct into a box.

Comment: oh more exactly why are you using `longtable` constructs such as `\endfirsthead` in a `tabularx` really it is impossible to answer just given disconnected fragments,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use the package `ltablex` which combines `tabularx` with `longtable` features. Sorry should have pointed that out.
Just to clarify: The table is on multiple pages and should adapt its font size that it takes up the most available space - in our example maximum width (maximum is `hsize`)!

Comment: why make people guess so many unstated details? I wrote half the code you are using and I would never have guessed enough to piece together a working example. Please always post a complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that shows the issue.

Comment: a MWE is included in the example/Use case I linked but I will include a MWE with my changes here as well

Comment: A minimal working example should be here and not in an external link. That means we should be able to compile the code you post. But we can't because it depends on stuff we don't have, such as `results.csv`. Please read the guidance provided at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?s=3|0.6324 which explains what is required and how to construct a suitable example.

Comment: You can't box something which runs to multiple pages so it makes no sense to use a multi page set-up with `\resizebox`. @DavidCarlisle explained this above. You could use `tabularx` or you could use `tabular`, but it has to go into a single box for you to resize the box. You can't resize the box if the thing won't go into the box in the first place.

Comment: @cfr thank you. Sorry I was not aware that I forgot to include a example CSV file. Yeah I understand that and that's why I asked this question in the first place.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking then. You know what the problem is, after all. Note, too, that if you are already setting the width of the table to the width of the text block, then  `\resizebox` would not alter the table anyway, even if it worked because the table is already as wide as it can be and no wider. So, the scale will be 1 horizontally. The `!` ensures that it will be scaled proportionately, so it will be scaled by 1 vertically. That is, nothing will change at all.